# Set Build Settings to show user friendly variable names instead of caps names

Tags: xcode

How do I configure so the names in the Project's Build Settings shows the user friendly names rather than the variable names in caps? I'm having this now

[image]

I would like it to be

[image]

It's readable but annoying as ADDITIONAL_SDKS is Additional SDKs, ARCHS is Architectures and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Xcode's Editor menu, choose Show Setting Titles instead of Show Setting Names.